# can't find module 'debug' error with Electron, Typescript and Electron packager

Tags: typescript, electron, electron-packager

I am using electron + typescript + electron packager to build an app.

I find that I must include the source .ts file and typescript .map file in the final app.

Or I get the can't find module 'debug' error.

How to make a functioning app without the source .ts and .map file in the final build?

Comment: I don't know the proper solution. I changed to electron builder, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify after create build, if you had been user `--asar` package command.

You can get reference from [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-packaging#archives-are-read-only)

If you want to edit your build at production mode then you should remove `--asar` from packager command.